# LibGDX error: Program type already present

Tags: android, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

```
Program type already present: 
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Pointer Message{kind=ERROR, 
text=Program type already present: 
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Pointer, 
sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Been searching for solution on this error for days and I can't find a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

One of the modules, perhaps "core", already contains this library
(freetype).
Try deleting it from the "android" section

//implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any freetype .
It was in the cache. So I just invalidated the cache using:

*File->invalidate cache and restart*

The second I had commented double implementation in all nodes like  in 'core' one:

```
buildscript {


repositories {//instructions
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:1.9.8'//this addon


}
```

and here in the same libGDX project gradle file:

```
project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
 //        implementation 'com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:1.9.8' }      }
```

, then I compiled and the error is gone.
Now it's finally able to produce APKs

(Not sure but, before all this have commented proguard path in android gradle file as well.)

Answer (score 0):

For me there was also this problem but telling me a class of my own was present already. I did not confuse any `api` or `implementation`, didn't have anything duplicate.

What helped me was to manually remove both the `android/build` directory and the `core/build` directory of my project and rerun it.